# Can i use openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate Server-Stubs?

Tags: openapi-generator

Is there a configuration for openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate Server-Stubs?

Thanx

Comment: Yes. See the documentation: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but i can not find the proper configuration to generate the server-stubs. Im i blind?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the  solution: By invoking the help command of the openapi-generator-cli.jar file you will see the list of all possible generators.